# PHP Write new array value by key or create new line

Tags: php, arrays

I want to read single array values with php and save them acoording to a key. If this key does not exists, a new entry should be created.

Here is my language fileTo read and write:

```
$LNG['name'] = array(
    1 => 'test',
    2 => 'test1',
    3 => 'test2',
    4 => 'test3',
    5 => 'test4',
);
```

Here is are Example

```
<?php
$include("TECH.php");

$name = $LNG['name'][$_GET['id']];
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Editpage</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
    <table>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td><td><input name="name" type="text" value="{$name}"/></td>
</tr>    
</table>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and by submit change value from the selected key

Example 
The key is 1 by Submit change value from key 1 to

```
$LNG['name'] = array(
    1 => 'i am edited',
    2 => 'test1',
    3 => 'test2',
    4 => 'test3',
    5 => 'test4',
);
```

For save i have tested with this

```
$file = 'TECH.php';
// The new person to add to the file
$saveedit = $LNG['tech'][$_GET['id']] = $_POST['name_ger'];
// Write the contents to the file, 
file_put_contents($file, $saveedit, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

and this add the edit name nothing he add a new entry

```
$LNG['name'] = array(
    1 => 'test',
    2 => 'test1',
    3 => 'test2',
    4 => 'test3',
    5 => 'test4',
);editvalue
```

Comment: Where do you want to save the array values ? I don't really get what you want, please be a bit more specific (Wo willst du die array elemente speichern? Ich verstehe/sehe nicht ganz was dein Ziel ist!)

Comment: I want to change about php individual values and if it is not available to add a new

Comment: Still dont get what are you asking for....

Comment: `if (array_key_exists())`

Answer (score 0):

So you want to store data in a file, in an array that PHP can “read” by simply including the file?

Then to modify that data, you can simply include the file as well, so that the variable/data structure `$LNG['name']` is present in your script that handles the submitted form.

To modify values, you simply overwrite them:

```
$LNG['name'][$idfromform] = $valuefromform;
```

Not necessary to check whether the key exists or not, PHP will create it automatically if it doesn’t.

And then, to get your modified data structure written back to the file, you simply use [`var_export`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) and [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

You might want to think about limiting what keys can be created in the array somehow though. And protect that form from being used by just any user of your site, otherwise you risk getting undesired side effects or might even create a security hole. But that largely depends on what you’ll do with the data structure afterwards.

Comment: have you a Example to save

Comment: The manual for both functions has examples of how they work. Please try something yourself first.

Comment: That's the problem I have tried a lot just nothing works what a pain that's what I had already tried that has stored data but also always put the old content and overwrote the old value is not

Comment: Just complaining that nothing you tried worked is not gonna help. Please edit your question again, showing what you have tried, and including a proper explanation of what you think it should do. (Inline comments inside the code are fine.)

Comment: So you ignored what I suggested here almost completely …

Comment: This was my first test before i write here for help
I can not do anything because even the examples are different than my rest